# Trying to download .apk file from within app. Getting "client identification header" error

Tags: android, apk, content-type, user-agent, http-get

This is a follow up question to [In-application update downloads from server not working. Service provider error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14684246/in-application-update-downloads-from-server-not-working-service-provider-error). I have changed the mobile internet settings to "do not adapt any sites", but now I am getting the following error message. `Your request did not supply a client identification header.`

I already tried `setHeader` for `HttpGet` as below, but this made no difference. What could this error message mean?

```
httpget.setHeader("Accept", "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
httpget.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
String userAgent = System.getProperty("http.agent");
httpget.setHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);
```

I can download the .apk with no problems from within the Android Internet Browser and the code is working on a different tablet and OS version on the same mobile carrier. Please any help or ideas are welcome. This is driving me crazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to manually define the user agent string as below. Worked after doing that.

```
String userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.2; en-us; SCH-I800 Build/FROYO) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1";
httpget.setHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);
```

Hope this helps someone with the same problem.